# Пунктуация при наличии развёрнутых деепричастных оборотов

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужно ли второе тире и правильно ли поставлена запятая после слова "обработку", не надо ли её поставить после "извращенца" в предложении: "Он, пройдя двойную обработку, - и этого скорпиона, и того извращенца - совсем перестанет быть тихим и домашним"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятую нужно переставить в конец вставки, так как она поясняет деепричастный оборот:
*Он, пройдя двойную обработку — и этого скорпиона, и того извращенца, — совсем перестанет быть тихим и домашним.*

Comment: Оleedd, спасибо!